# Trim textboxes and texareas on submit prevent form to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trimming all `textboxes and textareas on submit`. It does not work for all view pages.

I have taken simple `html inputs + kendo DropDownList + kendo AutoComplete` in my form.

Below is my submit method which doesn't work, when there are `Kendo UI control` on my form.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
   $('input[type=text], textarea').each(function () {
     if($(this).val()!=''){
       $(this).val($.trim($(this).val())); //Exception in chrome: paused on exception typeerror. Msg: undefined in not function.
     }
   });
});
```

I don't know what's wrong. I found this issue specific to `chrome browser`.

Comment: maybe there somewrong with this `$(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));`, try to add `alert('test')` after that if its not alerting the above code is wrong; and  if($(this).val()) would be find (no need to have this `!=''`)

Comment: @Niang it is working. there is no issue in trim.

Comment: @Niang happen for chrome only

Comment: Are you using document.ready in your view? Have you checked by putting an `alert` inside `submit click scope`?

Comment: Have you checked your Browser Console? The Same workout is working fine in Chrome. Take a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw452/1/)

Comment: @RJK I am using document.ready() and submit is inside it. In chrome it pause on exception 'typeerror'. message: undefined is not a function.

Comment: I think you have a problem in defining the `click` event may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong. So I updated the function as below:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
   $('#textbox1,#textbox2,#textarea1').each(function () {
     if($(this).val()!=''){
       $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
     }
   });
});
```

I wrote ids of all textboxes and textarea which I need to trim inside each. And it works fine. But still I have question why generalize function didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It it just the kendo controls? Their DropDownList for instance renders this (from the demo)

```
<input id="color" value="1" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
```

Note there is no `type=text` attribute so your selector is probably not including this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no problem in your normal HTML and Js code. Check other piece of codes in your project, Weather its blocking your code.

> Probably check the Kendo UI Syntax / Format / Attributes for Html
>   controls. It might be a problem.

Take a look at my [fiddle workout](http://jsfiddle.net/xw452/1/). I have Tested its working fine.

There is `no` exception Like -- `//Exception in chrome: paused on exception typeerror`